# Zaurus and mapping keyboards

Tags: keyboard-layout

Is there still somebody using a `Zaurus`?
I got a second-hand SL-C3000 with ROM version *1.11 JP* and kernel *2.4.20*, and I cannot manage to remap keys. There is no `xmodmap`, just an application "`KeyMapHelper`" which generates a keymap in text mode.